# Excluding New Dependencies in Gradle File

Tags: kotlin, dependencies, build.gradle

I have an app that runs perfectly without new dependencies like this one:

A newer version of androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx than 2.4.2 is available: 2.5.0

If I upgrade to v.2.5.0, my app has warnings about unrelated elements like  for example references to menu objects.

Should I wait and allow these Gradle warnings such as above notice until another upgrade comes along and try the new dependency then?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to update anything unless you have a reason to. It's often a good idea (as well as new features you also get bug fixes) but it's usually not required. Specifying all your dependency versions means you get a repeatable build that should always work, so long as those versions are available

The thing about libraries is they often have dependencies on other libraries, and updating one might introduce a requirement for other stuff to be updated (which might be why you're seeing other errors appear. That *broadly* shouldn't happen (making things independently updateable is part of the reason for breaking everything out into separate libraries!) but [here's a blog post from when they introduced it](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/hello-world-androidx.html):

> Starting with the AndroidX refactor, library versions have been reset from 28.0.0 to 1.0.0. Future updates will be versioned on a per-library basis, following strict semantic versioning rules where the major version indicates binary compatibility. This means, for example, that a feature may be added to RecyclerView and used in your app without requiring an update to every other library used by your app. *This also means that libraries depending on androidx may provide **reasonable guarantees** about binary compatibility with future releases of AndroidX -- that **a dependency on a 1.5.0 revision will still work when run against 1.7.0 but will likely not work against 2.0.0.***

Really you have to look at the release notes for a library to see if there are any breaking changes you need to worry about. For example, [here's the one for the `Activity` Jetpack component](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity) and if you search *"dependency changes"* you'll see where updating actually requires a specific minimum version of another thing

Also sometimes a library will pull in an old version of another library it depends on, so you might be explicitly interacting with a very old version of a component just because you never added it as a dependency yourself. Then if that first library requires a much newer version of that dependency, you might suddenly get a large jump that requires a bunch of changes to your code, even though it doesn't seem to have anything to do with what you updated!